# Xcode 4.2 on Lion: beachballs and crashes far too often

Tags: xcode, crash

Since switching to Mac OS X Lion and Xcode 4, I experience lots of beach balling and a few crashes a day. Not project dependent. Often when starting an app in the simulator the debugger waits for ages "attaching...", when a re-run usually starts the app immediately. Anyone else with these experiences?

I'm on a 2.26GHz Intel core 2 duo mac mini with 4G mem, xcode 4.2.1 Build 4D502

[added]
It definitely is a memory management issue. Especially with Photoshop Elements along the system grinds to a halt for sure. And I did spot a gigantic mds process too 2.69 GB?? Let me switch that off.. (sudo mdutil -a -i off), and restrict Photoshop's memory use.

[added] 
This is an "early 2009" mac mini, supposedly with a limit of 4G on the max installed memory. However, it is stated that "unofficially" you can install 8G (2x4G). For under 50 euro I'm willing to try that and (hopefully) soothe my nerves! http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/stats/mac-mini-core-2-duo-2.26-late-2009-specs.html

Comment: I have as well with a variety of machines with similar specs. Can't say for sure, but I think it is more Lion than Xcode. At least from what I hear.

Comment: ...is exactly the reason I did not upgrade to Lion. Both get installed via the AppStore, and I have too much other development stuff installed to risk it. MySQL, php, Ruby...

Answer (score 0):

The added 4GB memory seems to have solved my problems. This means that, at least on my machine, 4GB (now 8) mac mini 2.66, Xcode 4.2 with Lion is a non-working combination.